# How to deploy deployment slot specific appsettings from git repo?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I do realize I can use Azure AppSettings to override settings in Web.Config files.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing says:

- App settings (can be configured to stick to a slot)
- Connection strings (can be configured to stick to a slot)

So far so good.
But how do I **version** these settings?
I don't want to add them manually through the Azure Portal.

Also I don't exactly understand why I can add custom application settings in the Azure App Service release pipeline task. These settings are then copied to the configured slot. Consider following scenario...

There is a new appsetting (which would usually live in Web.Config).
Okay Web.Config is not a good idea because it is specific per deployment slot. So you add it to the release task configuration - for your "staging" slot.
Next you swap staging and production - and of course the new production system has no clue about the new setting (not even the staging configuration which would anyway be equally bad).

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set the appsettings stick to a slot in vsts?

Comment: In VSTS yes - but not necessarily in the release pipeline. Closer to the application. GitOps. I only want to have security sensitive information in the release pipeline such as connection strings.

Comment: I want these settings to be part of source control. I want to commit changes and have the new/changes/removed settings automatically go to the proper deployment slots.